# CompletableFuture.get() stuck, not returning result

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, completable-future

I have a Java code snippet that uses CompletableFuture to retrieve data asynchronously.

```
@GetMapping("/voyagePointData/{reportType}")
@PreAuthorize("@generalGuard.isResourceAllowed(authentication, #accountId) && hasAuthority('acl.map.device.READ')")
public ResponseEntity<List<ReportVoyagePointBean>> getVoyagePointData(@RequestParam(value = "accountId") int accountId,
                                                                      @RequestParam(value = "ids") Set<Integer> ids,
                                                                      @RequestParam("dateFrom") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime dateFrom,
                                                                      @RequestParam("dateTo") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime dateTo,
                                                                      @RequestParam(value = "onlySkipped") boolean onlySkipped,
                                                                      @PathVariable(value = "reportType") String reportType,
                                                                      @AuthenticationPrincipal UserBean userBean) throws NoDataException {
    AccountEntity account = accountService.findById(accountId).orElseThrow(() -> new NoDataException("Account not exist"));
    ZoneId userTimeZone = ZoneId.of(userBean.getUserTimeZone());
    DateTimeFormatter zoneTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ModelsConstants.PATTERN_TIME_ONLY_MINUTES).withZone(userTimeZone);
    CompletableFuture<List<ReportVoyagePointBean>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            return reportService.getVoyagePointData(
                    new ReportInfoBean(dateFrom, dateTo, account, userBean.getUserTimeZone(), zoneTimeFormatter), ids, reportType, onlySkipped);
        } catch (NoDataException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }, executorService);

    try {
        List<ReportVoyagePointBean> result = future.get();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } 
}
```

However, when I call future.get(), it gets stuck and doesn't return anything, leading to infinite waiting. If I call reportService.getVoyagePointData without CompletableFuture and with the same parameters, it works fine and returns all data.

Things I've tried that didn't help:

- call CompletableFuture for each ID in loop and then joining them to
  one list
- added ExecutorService with different initialization like
  fixedThreadPool with specified timeout or newCachedThreadPool
- added final block where I call executorService.shutdown()
- used Future instead of CompletableFuture

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:
Initializations of ExecutorService that I tried:

```
private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
//and using this config 
@Configuration
public class ExecutorConfig {
    @Bean
    public ExecutorService getExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 5, 4, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(50), Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), new RejectedExecutionHandlerImpl());
    }
}
```

Comment: How is executorService initialized?

Comment: Why do you call `executorService.shutdown();` after that single job? Of course, subsequent executions of this method will hang after the `executorService` has been shut down.

Comment: @Matteo NNZ I edited my post and added info about executorService initialization

Comment: @Holger , when I first wrote this code, I didn't use executorService.shutdown(), it's here because I tried different solution to fix it

Comment: Do you understand that after shutting down an executor service it will not process any jobs? So how did you come to the idea that this could solve your problem? I suggest you first remove everything that stems from an attempt to solve your problem, then check whether the problem still exists, and post the minimal code.

Comment: @Holger, I tried again without  executorService.shutdown() and result the same. I edited code above accordingly.

Comment: Still, check `executorService.isShutdown()` in the method. Note that the `CompletableFuture` is obsolete, the way you use it here. You can simply use `Future<List<ReportVoyagePointBean>> future = executorService.submit(() -> reportService.getVoyagePointData(new ReportInfoBean(dateFrom, dateTo, account, userBean.getUserTimeZone(), zoneTimeFormatter), ids, reportType, onlySkipped));`

Comment: Try to use the method with one argument `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doSomething())` for the debug purposes.

Comment: What is the purpose of an asynchronous call that you’re synchronously waiting for?  Why not just `List<ReportVoyagePointBean> result = reportService.getVoyagePointData(…);`?

Comment: @VGR because it processes great amount of data and takes to long

Comment: That makes sense, but… when you call `future.get()` you are waiting for the task to finish anyway.  So you gain nothing by using CompletableFuture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The main reason for this error was my entites that were part of my code inside CompletableFuture and some part of these entities are lazy initialized and they needed to connect to db in order to fetch data. I solved this by creating a DTO and initialize it above CompletableFuture.